# Struggling to get PHP variable to work in MySQL Select request

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to get my code to pull up a username based on the password a user inputs. It works successfully when I bake the actual password into the code, but I haven't found any way to get the variable in successfully.

The troublesome line is:

```
$result=$dbh->prepare('SELECT * from account WHERE password = (' & $formpassword & ')');
```

The variable is $formpassword.

I have variables successfully working on an INSERT statement elsewhere in my code, using this system:

```
    $_query = "INSERT INTO account (username, password) ";

  $_query = $_query."VALUES ('".$formusername."', '".$formpassword."')";
```

^^^ I have tried using the above system for my SELECT statement, but it doesn't appear to work either.

Sorry if my post is unclear or anything, I'm not remotely experienced with programming...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As you used in the second example, the PHP concatenation operator is `.`, not `&`. The whole point of preparing statements though is to **not** include variables directly into the query, but to use placeholders and then bind the variables to the placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Never store plain text passwords! Please use PHP's [built-in functions](https://www.atyantik.com/managing-passwords-correct-way-php/) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

When using prepared statements you put placeholders in the sql.

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare('SELECT * from account WHERE password = :formPassword');
$stmt->execute([':formPassword'=>$formpassword]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();


$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO account (username, password) VALUES (:username, :formPassword)');
$stmt->execute([':username'=>$formusername,':formPassword'=>$formpassword]);
```

Comment: You don't actually need the colon in the execute part.
`$stmt->execute(['formPassword'=>$formpassword]);` would work.

Comment: @benyafai I've seen arguments for and against. idk what the correct answer is. For me it comes down to does it hurt having it.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to use " (Double quotes) instead of ' (Single quotes). Then you can just use the variable without concatenation.

```
$result=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * from account WHERE( password = $formpassword )");
```

Comment: Since it is a prepare I'm assuming you are wanting to sanitize the password. In that case you will want to pass the variables into it.

```
$result=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * from account WHERE( password = %s )",$formpassword);
```

Comment: Still, don't do this. See Jason K's answer.